# pointcloud2 problem

Tags: ros, rviz, camera-info-manager, rostopic, stere-image-proc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know that there are lots of question on his topic but after going through most of them i was not able to find solution for my problem

- I am using `stereo_image_proc` for getting point cloud from stereo cam driver as i have provided below, i successfully gets both left and right camera output but i cant see pointcloud2 in rviz
- I tried echoing the `camera/point2` topic but the result seems weird[**or is it ok ,I am new to these stuffs?**][image: image description]
  [image: image description]
- is my output ok?if yes then what might be the reason i dont get pointcloud in rviz(I have tried rotating the window)

**Edit:** sorry after i again tried rotating i got the cloud but it seems weird [image: rviz_result]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224984/pointcloud2-problem/) by [Azharudeen](https://answers.ros.org/users/23697/azharudeen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2016-01-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The output is probably reasonable, as that is the array of uint8's that make up the images/point clouds. You can add the `--noarr` option to `rostopic echo` to get a more reasonable output.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2016-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Azharudeen](https://answers.ros.org/users/23697/azharudeen/) on 2016-02-26**:
Thanks william for your replay